# So many views on message in Telegram but only 1 person in private channel

Tags: networking, viewer, telegram-messenger, bots

I forwarded a document from a channel on telegram to my own private channel that only had me in it. The document had 2,000 views on the eye icon in the original channel. When I forwarded it from the original channel to my own channel, the 2,000 views remained. How can this be if I am the only subscriber/ administrator and it was a private channel?

Is it possible that the the first channel had created/bought fake views using a bot for that document and it carried over when I forwarded to my channel?

I also never sent it anywhere else.

Please help. I'm freaking out.

Answer (score 0):

A forwarded message in Telegram (that is forwarded with the regular way and it shows the channel it's forwarded from) shows the view count combined for the source and forwarded ones.

So the views you're seeing is from people viewing it in the source channel (or other channels that also had it forwarded to them.)

From the [Telegram FAQ](https://telegram.org/faq_channels#q-what-does-the-eye-icon-mean):

> Each post in a channel has a view counter. **Views from forwarded
> copies of your messages are also included in the total count.** This
> way you can see how far it has spread.
>
> Please note that these numbers are approximate — we don't want to keep
> a record for everything you've ever viewed.